# Replacing Dockerfile registry references in Go vendor directory

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, docker-registry, vendoring

I've got a Go project that contains several vendored directories that (in some cases) contain Dockerfiles that reference docker.io registries.

This worked well, until security compliance scans and new corporate requirements banned third party registries anywhere in the codebase, including the vendor directory.

We need these dependencies and can mirror any third party images, but I'm not sure of the proper way to exclude and replace the docker.io references in vendored Dockerfiles.

Anyone have insight or some documentation I can catch up on?

Comment: If it's vendored, you're not going to directly change it. Perhaps you can get upstream to make a change, but the question I'd have is if it makes sense to flag a file that you aren't building? Typically, scans for things like linting and code quality exclude vendored directories.